# Using a function's output (defined locally) inside SSH call

Tags: shell-script, ssh, quoting, here-document

I have created a function

```
function getqueue() {
    urlqueuename="urlcall"    
    ouput=`curl $urlqueuename`
    queue=$(echo $ouput | jq -r '.queueName')
    echo $queue
}
```

I am using a ssh call from my script like:

```
ssh -T -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "$HOME_DIR/<pemfile>" $username@$IP<<EOF
queue=$(getqueue)
echo "Queue name : $queue"
EOF
```

But the **queue** is coming as empty, Tried also with `$(typeset -f)` to use functions in remote call, but still the variable is empty

Any guidance regarding the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The heredoc is unquoted, so the function is executed locally. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes I want to execute this function locally and use the return value in ssh connection.

Comment: Does `getqueue` actually return anything when run outside of the `ssh`?   Is `urlcall` a placeholder for an actual URL, or is it supposed to be a global variable name `$urlcall`? (btw, don't use global variables in functions - pass in the values you need as arguments)   Also, all the code in that function could be replaced with a single line: `curl 'urlcall' | jq -r .queueName`.

Comment: Yes urlcall is a placeholder , Cant disclose the actual URL.
Yes function does return value when called outside the ssh paradigm

Comment: `echo "Queue name: \$queue"` note the backslash. Without it you get the value of `$queue` *when the here-document is read*, not the value assigned in the here-document.

Comment: Why not more simply `function getqueue() { curl "$urlqueuename" | jq -r '.queueName'; }`? No need for intermediate variables and command substitution if you're going to write the result verbatim to stdout anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The here-document is unquoted, this mean that variable expansion and command substitution are made as the document is formed, locally.  In this case, it will not have the desired effect as it would end up as something like

```
queue=somevalue
echo "Queue name : "
```

That is, it would expand to a script that sets the value of the `queue` variable, but since the variable is also expanded inside the string printed by `echo`, its correct value (at the time of execution) will never be displayed.

Note that this expansion is done even before `ssh` is called.

If the `curl` call etc. needs to happen on the remote host (there wouldn't really be a reason to send a here-document script over otherwise, or to do the `ssh` call at all), then quote the here-document.  You do this by using `<<'EOF'`.

However, this also means that the function `getqueue` needs to be defined in the environment of the remote script.  You either have to include that function in the here-document, or pick out the needed bits.

Since the function is basically just doing

```
curl urlcall | jq -r '.queueName'
```

you could do

```
ssh -T -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "$HOME_DIR/<pemfile>" "$username@$IP" <<'REMOTE_SCRIPT'
queue=$(curl urlcall | jq -r '.queueName')
printf 'The queue name is "%s"\n' "$queue"
REMOTE_SCRIPT
```

If some expansions need to be happening locally and others remotely, then *don't* quote the here-document, but escape the `$` that should be expanded remotely.  For example,

```
ssh user@server <<SCRIPT
remote_var=\$( something )

printf 'remote_var = "%s", local_var = "%s"\n' "\$remote_var" "$local_var"
SCRIPT
```

In the above example, `remote_var` is being set remotely.  We can't assign a value to `local_var` in the here-document (and expect to be able to use `$local_var` with that value, for the same reasons as above), but the `printf` call will print the value that the variable had at the time when the here-document was expanded (just before the call to `ssh`).

Comment: Thanks , i cant use quotes cos there are other variables which needs to be expanded inside the SSH, Is there a combination of these two together?

Comment: @AjithSasidharan I have updated the answer.

Comment: Can you have stuff inside REMOTE_SCRIPT run via locally defined function instead? For example if you do multiple commands it would be way nicer to manage, and also syntax highlighting is correct and logic split when writing code. 
Something like ssh your_ssh_credentials_here locally_defined_function_with_variables_defined_locally_too

Comment: @trainoasis There are other questions on this site regarding calling shell functions via `ssh`. I'm on my phone right now, so it's inconvenient to search...

Comment: Indeed there are, found many, but none doing what I want so far :)) No worries wont stop searching

Comment: @trainoasis In that case it sounds as if you may want to ask a new question. But if you do, make sure to reference similar questions and describe in what way they don't help you.

Comment: @Kusalananda will do just that, ty